# cryptico RSA encryption/decryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, cryptico

I have generated public and private key and stored it to the local storage for further use but when i try to decrypt with the private key that is stored in the local storage i get some strange error.

```
    var Bits = 1024;
    var privateKey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);
    var publicKey = cryptico.publicKeyString(privateKey);

    storageService.set('clientPrivate', privateKey);
    storageService.set('clientPublic', publicKey);*/

    var privateKey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);
    var publicKey = cryptico.publicKeyString(privateKey);

    var PlainText = "Matt, I need you to help me with my Starcraft strategy.";
    var encrypted = cryptico.encrypt(PlainText, publicKey);

    console.log('Public key: ' + publicKey);
    console.log('Private key: ' + privateKey);
    console.log('Encrypted: ' + encrypted.chiper);

    var dec = cryptico.decrypt(encrypted.cipher, privateKey);
    console.log(dec.plaintext);
```

If i create new keys for every use then it works but not when i store them to local storage.

I found that before i save private key to local storage:

```
console.log(privateKey);
```

the output looks like this:

```
RSAKey {}
```

and when I display data from local storage it like this:

```
Object {}
```

I assume that maybe this is the problem but don't know how to solve it.

Edited code for getting the data from local storage:

```
angular.module('cashregisterApp')
.service('storageService', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    return {
        get: function(key, callback) {
            // get value for that key
            chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(value) {
                var ret = [];
                if (key === null) {
                    ret = value;
                } else {
                    for (var a = 0; a < key.length; a++) {
                        if (typeof value[key[a]] !== 'undefined') {
                            // Add specfic value to array for this key
                            ret[key[a]] = value[key[a]];
                        } else {
                            // Set to null because it is not defined
                            ret[key[a]] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                callback(ret);
            });
        },
        set: function(key, value, callback) {
            // set key and value
            var keyValue = {};
            keyValue[key] = value;
            // check callback
            if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
                callback = function(){};
            }
            chrome.storage.local.set(keyValue, function() { callback(); });
        },
        remove: function(key, callback) {
            // remove only one key value pair
            chrome.storage.local.remove(key, function() {
                callback();
            });
        },
        clear: function(callback) {
            // remove everything
            chrome.storage.local.clear(function() {
                callback();
            });
        }
    };
```

});

Comment: It would be useful to see the code regarding storageService and how you retrieve the data. Regardless, are you aware that localStorage doesn't store object types? It only stores strings. So if you are storing a JSON object, you should stringify it to save, and then parse it once you read.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Comment: I wasn't aware that local storage isn't  storing object types. I tried this with stringify and then save it to LocalStorage and then parse it back, but i stil ge  Object {} back

Comment: You can try to save it to localStorage and then console.log(localStorage) to see all of its content. Values in localStorage are all strings, so it's strange that you are getting an Object{} 
Could we see the code that stores and retrieves the value?

Comment: @Gerard You can see the code for getting the data from local storage. I forgot to say that this is packed app fro chrome store. I Tried to save my own object to local storage some json object and it was stored as an object I load it from local storage and access the data of the object. i don't know how to do this anymore. :) maybe if you know of any other way how to generate the public and private key and then store them for later use?

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were using localStorage  
You could try the following:  
    var privateKey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);
    var publicKey = cryptico.publicKeyString(privateKey);
    localStorage.publicKey = JSON.stringify(publicKey);
    localStorage.privateKey = JSON.stringify(privateKey );

And then to retrieve:
    var publicKey = JSON.parse(localStorage.publicKey)
    var privateKey = JSON.parse(localStorage.privateKey )
chrome.storage is asynchronous and you have to deal with callbacks. localStorage is synchronous, so maybe will work for you

Comment: I tried that, i decided not to save to local storage but to always generate key pair :) but now i have totaly different problem, beacuse i can't decrypt this with php.